# Keep getting correlation-id errors on Lists when creating SharePoint online site using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I keep getting correlation-id errors on all Lists when creating SharePoint online sites using CSOM. I am using example http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/create-site-collections-with-csom-in.html. Furthermore the site is being ceated correctly (except for all lists, including siteassets)

I changed all of the references in my c# console application pointing to version 15 or 16 dlls (64-bits). No difference.

> Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant (version 16.0.2617.1200)

Located:

C:\Program Files\SharePoint Client Components\16.0\Assemblies\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
```

Anyone any idea what is causing this issue? It drives me mad! Cannot figure it out.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Site collections take a few minutes to spin up. Could it be possible that you're hitting the site before everything is provisioned?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the solution to this issue. Appeared to be the wrong TimeZoneId property value was set. This was causing the correlation-id errors. Needed to be value **4** for (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlijn, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Wenen

To figure out the correct TimeZoneId needed execute code below on any existing site.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("site url"); 
var culture = context.Web.RegionalSettings; 
context.Load(culture); 
var tz = culture.TimeZone; 
context.Load(tz); 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 
context.Dispose();
```